# Keep alive a SSL connection on iOS

Tags: ssl, uiwebview, nsurlconnection, cfnetwork

Here is my work flow for an app on iOS 8:

1. I open an UIWebView
2. Open a webpage
3. Server requires authentication.
4. I authenticate to the server using a client certificate stored in a p12 file.
5. I can access all the pages stored on the server with no problem (BTW, the site is single paged, and makes AJAX request to the server)
6. If I leave my app idle for 10 minutes, I can no longer make any request, and get this error message in the console

> CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824 -> -9829)
>       NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9829)

Now, I understand this is because the TSL session expires after 10 minutes on the device and I have to open it again. How can I do that? I don't get any callbacks in my code.

Related to this issue is this article: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1727/_index.html